# Connecting two computers directly with ethernet for sharing files?

Tags: networking, ssh, ethernet

I'm a beginner in networking and was wondering if it would be possible to connect two laptops directly using something like a LAN crossover cable through their respective ethernet ports and then use Unix utilities (assuming they exist for such a purpose) for communicating solely between them without any other devices being involved. I suppose it would no longer be a network then, but I'm just curious about the following:

```
  ___                    ___
 |___|  <--LAN cable--> |___|
/__A__\                /__B__\
```

1. Would this be practical in a niche scenario where suppose you don't have any network and need to constantly move files from one laptop to another as an alternative to say, repeatedly plugging in and plugging out a USB stick from one to the other to move files?
2. What Unix utilities could exist for such a use-case ? for example, one would use `scp` or `rsync` to move files from A to B over a network, except here there is no network.
3. Would it be any different than serial interfaces like UART or RS232?

Comment: What you want to do is called an ad-hoc connection.  You probably don't even need to use a crossover cable. "*What Unix utilities could exist ...*" -- Don't refer to "*Unix*" if you're actually using Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done it before.. I did it once before the days of wireless lans, when I had an issue with my "wired NAT router" where the speed was slow, so I connected the two computers directly.

Each one is accessed with an IP address.

So from the point of view of what commands you use, it's exactly the same as if they were on your network. So you would use standard OS file sharing protocols.

How are files shared between two linux computers(if not going across the internet)? NFS https://www.wikihow.com/Share-Files-Between-Linux-Computers-Using-NFS

Once you have a file system of a computer mounted onto your computer, then you can use regular linux commands like cp(copy).

You mention SCP.. That's part of SSH as is SFTP(which people use more than SCP). But SSH and those SSH based things like SCP or SFTP, are used when a computer is across the internet.  And when you can SSH to a computer then SSHFS can be used to mount it. And then commands like cp can apply a bit like with local file sharing. Technically you can use SSH and other commands that use SSH, when within your local network too.

You could use an SSH based solution but NFS which is very native, would be more normal. NFS is the Linux equivalent of SMB which is what Windows computers use natively.  A Linux computer can run SAMBA and access a Windows computer on your LAN. (or connected via a cross-over cable).

Two computers connected together is a network. Over a short distance, so, a LAN.

Answer (score 5):

You are overthinking this.  If you have 2 computers with standard gigabit connections you can connect them to each other with a normal ethernet cables (gigabit cables do auto crossover detection. Older standards need a crossover cables).

The next thing is to statically assign the IP addresses on both computers, making sure they are in the same subnet. For example 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2 with a netmask of 255.255.255.0 (or /24).

At this point the computers can talk directly to each other on IP address and you can use the normal protocols - ssh, samba, an ftp client/server, an nfs client/server, http (but not https because of certs), rsync will all work.

You may want to add names for both systems to /etc/hosts to help with DNS resolution issues you may experience.

This connection is a standard ethernet connection - a network of 2 machines with no default gateway - and it behaves like a standard tcp connection, using ethernet, no need for rs232 or PPP related protocols.