# Trouble connecting two local computers with ethernet cable

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

I can't seem to get a `ping` from the conection (PC1 to PC2 directly connected with a CAT5 factory cable), but `arping` does just fine. Clarification: IPv4 is not functional though a datalink is pressent and functional, I read the wikipedia article on ARP, I know the difference. I also tried to `ping -I eth0 addr` without success.

The pocedure as follows: connect PC1 to PC2 via ethernet; start `udhcpd` on PC1; start `udhcpc` on PC2; confirm dhcp OFFER and ACK on PC1; confirm address on PC2; ping in either direction (PC1: 100% packet loss, PC2: Network Unreachable)
Note: manually setting IPs results in the above, sans, dhcp.
Note: udhcpd settings.

```
# ip addr add 192.168.1.1/32|24 # tried both 24&32 for subnet
# /etc/udhcpd.conf
interface eth0  
lease_file /var/lib/udhcpd/udhcpd.leases  
start 192.168.1.2  
end 192.168.1.255 
# udhcpd -f -I 192.168.1.1
```

I am not sure what is wrong as this has worked before as is, it seams that udhcpc/d does not assign routes and I am currently looking into it.
I have also read the Arch wiki regarding networks and ad-hoc though since I'm using Artix on PC1 and busybox/Linux on PC2, it only marginally applies, I have also read articles and manuals without systemd, which I do not remember the referances to.

The reason I'm even trying is to have PC2 as a NAS/IP-USB expansion hub/whatever else I come up with

```
# routel 
Dst             Gateway         Prefsrc         Protocol Scope   Dev              Table
default         192.168.114.214 192.168.114.220 dhcp             usb0             
127.0.0.0/8     127.0.0.1                                        lo               
192.168.1.0/24                  192.168.1.1     kernel   link    eth0             
192.168.114.0/24                 192.168.114.220 dhcp     link    usb0             
127.0.0.0/8                     127.0.0.1       kernel   host    lo               local
127.0.0.1                       127.0.0.1       kernel   host    lo               local
127.255.255.255                 127.0.0.1       kernel   link    lo               local
192.168.1.1                     192.168.1.1     kernel   host    eth0             local
192.168.1.255                   192.168.1.1     kernel   link    eth0             local
192.168.114.220                 192.168.114.220 kernel   host    usb0             local
192.168.114.255                 192.168.114.220 kernel   link    usb0             local
```

is on PC1 while PC2 `route` is empty.

---

**Old Note**: `ip a` on PC1 shows the expected 192.168.1.1/24 however on PC2 it's 192.168.1.150/0; differing subnets if I'm reading this right: https://superuser.com/a/1724094/1719820

**Note**: new procedure.
After booting *both* machenes into Minimal Linux Live (previously busybox/Linux) I tried to run only the dhcp server on PC1 and only the dhcp client on PC2 with default settings resulting in PC1's ip of `192.168.0.1/32` and PC2's ip of `192.168.0.20/32` still no routes though and `ping` on both sides results in `network unreachable`, manual IP assignment does not work.

Comment: What options are you using for udhcpd?

Comment: If its just 2 PCs, why bother with DHCP? You can just connect them statically?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek read the part about that not working either, it was the first thing I tried actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has arrisen from not fully understanding the problem at hand (IPv4 and the network stack) and missing important though easely overlooked clues (mml's udhcpc script at boot notifying of lacking netmask/gateway).

The actual problem was that udhcpd, while it did the DHCP part it, for as of yet unknown reasons, did not do the netmask/gateway part or I am missing crucial configuration.

The solution is a straight forward one too: set the IP/NetMask/GateWay.
via `ip` from the iproute2 package

```
# ip set link 'iface' up
# ip addr add 'local'/'netmask' dev 'iface'
# ip route add 'remote'/'netmask' via 'local' dev 'iface'
# ping 'remote'
```

Explaining the variables:
`iface` - the interface on the local machene
`local` - the IP address of the local machene (local as in the machene you are entering the commands on)
`netmask` - self explanatory, should be the same on both sides, writen as either [0-32] or ip in increments of 64, i.e. 255.255.255.128 though ususally it's in increments of 256
`remote` - the IP address of the remote machene (remote as in the machene you want to connect with the local one and vice versa)
when adding the route make sure your remote machene has it's ip already assigned

Answer (score -1):

All you describe is perfectly logic. I will explain in detail what's happening.

> I can't seem to get a ping from the conection (PC1 to PC2 directly connected with a CAT5 factory cable), but arping does just fine.

This behavior is totally normal, `arping` is a command that use `ARP` protocol (layer **2 & 3** of `OSI model`) to check the connectivity with another machine in the same subnet. It does not use `IPv4 / IPv6` to communicate. So for me it's logic it works.

However, `ping` protocol uses ICMP (layer **3** of `OSI model`) which needs a correct routes table in **both side** and correct `IPv4 / IPv6` addresses (in your case, only IPv4).

> (PC1: 100% packet loss, PC2: Network Unreachable)

This behavior is totally normal as `PC2` does not have any route. Packets can't transit and are blocked once they arrive in `PC2`.

> ip a on PC1 shows the expected 192.168.1.1/24 however on PC2 it's 192.168.1.150/0

Here is your issue, `PC2`'s `IPv4` **is invalid** : `192.168.1.150/0`. You can't have an `IPv4` with `/0` as subnet mask for `IPv4 procotol`, the minimum is `/1`. Furthermore, both machines **are not in the same network**. To communicate, those machines would need a router (assuming `/0` is correct). The ping can't work with this configuration.

You have an issue with the `PC2`'s `IPv4` that also breaks the routes table on it. You need to check in your `DHCP` server configuration that distribute IP for `PC2`. The goal is to have the same mask in both machines so : `/24` or `255.255.255.0`. Once done, you will be able to ping and communicate in both directions (you just need to care of internal firewall (`Windows Firewall` / `iptables` rules etc...).

You can also try to fix the IP on `PC2` instead of use `DHCP` protocol. It should works perfectly too.

Note that put two `DHCP` servers in the same network requires a little bit more though and setup - You can refer to this post [here](https://serverfault.com/a/368517). You can put only one `udhcpd` on `PC1` and use it to distribute IPs for all machines in the subnet (including itself).

Comment: The hosts _are_ in the same network, though – even if the subnet masks do not match, each host's subnet still includes the opposite host's address, so both hosts will (well, _should_) think that the other host is in their local network. It's the complete lack of routes in PC2's routing table that is worrying, though.

Comment: I think the lack of routes can be explained by the invalid IP on `PC2`. There is definitely a connection.

Comment: Thank for the reply! I do know that arping and ping are different: it's the first thing I tried to figure out, I only included it as proof that there is a link betwix the hosts. I also don't have two DHCP servers on PC1; a DHCP server fort eth0 and a client for usb0. I also figured that a subnet of /0 is bad, so I booted both machenes into Minimal Linux Live and did the whole shtick again, now PC2 had a propper subnet of /32 but there were still no routes, this is something I will further investigate